# Multistep rounding to an integer?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm newbie.

I have the number

> 2,4579

I know that this is wrong

> 2,4579 → 3

Is this true in mathematics?

> 2,4579→2,458→2,46→2,5→3

I mean can I have true result for

> 2,4579 → 3

using multistep rounding?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't round off while calculating. In other words only round off once in the end when you have the result.

Of course sometimes you just have to use approximate numbers and the error could accumulate and give a mistake in the final result. But usually (if you use enough precision and the calculation isn't exceedingly lengthy) there shouldn't be this problem.